# SSO Okta not returning back to app after login

Tags: android, single-sign-on, okta, appauth

I am trying to configure **SSO Authentication** for my android app. I found a tutorial on below link,

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab/#0

It shows **SSO** example based on Google.

I am using **Okta** for this purpose, I created Application on **Okta** and copied Client id and redirect url from it to my project.

When I use Google URLs(auth and token endpoint, client id, redirect Url), it is working fine, i.e. it's redirecting to google login page and after entering valid credentials, it's returning back to my app.

And while using **Okta URLs**(auth and token endpoint, client id, redirect Url), it's redirecting me to Okta Login page properly, but after entering valid credentials, it's not returning back to my app, i.e. the login page is not getting closed.

Below is code which I am using for **SSO** login,

```
AuthorizationServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = new AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
    //Uri.parse("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth") /* google auth endpoint */,
    //Uri.parse("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token") /* google token endpoint */
    Uri.parse("https://dev-636680.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize") /* okta auth endpoint */,
    Uri.parse("https://dev-636680.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token") /* okta token endpoint */
);

//String clientId = "511828570984-fuprh0cm7665emlne3rnf9pk34kkn86s.apps.googleusercontent.com";  // google 
String clientId = "0oahkjjk3oszDWqvZ356";                                // Okta
//Uri redirectUri = Uri.parse("com.google.codelabs.appauth:/oauth2callback");      // google
Uri redirectUri = Uri.parse("com.okta.dev-636680:/callback");            //okta
AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
    serviceConfiguration,
    clientId,
    AuthorizationRequest.RESPONSE_TYPE_CODE,
    redirectUri
);
builder.setScopes("openid", "profile", "offline_access", "email");

AuthorizationRequest request = builder.build();

AuthorizationService authorizationService = new 
    AuthorizationService(view.getContext());

String action = "com.google.codelabs.appauth.HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE";
Intent postAuthorizationIntent = new Intent(action);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(view.getContext(), request.hashCode(), postAuthorizationIntent, 0);
authorizationService.performAuthorizationRequest(request, pendingIntent);
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.